# Validation summary message pops up twice

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validationsummary

I have validation controls in my page and I am using Validation summary message box to display the validation messages,the javascript function shown below worked for me but the problem is I am using this javascript function on OnClientClick event of the button and when I click the button with form controls not been filled its displaying the validation summary message box as expected but when i close the summary box it's getting displayed again and i need to close the message box to disappear, means i have to do two clicks everytime. Can somebody correct me what am I doing wrong.

Here is what I am doing:-

```
 <asp:Button ID="SubmitButtonOne" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitButtonOne_Click"
                         ValidationGroup="Cases" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="PleaseWaitShow()" />
```

Here is the javascript function:

```
function PleaseWaitShow() {
                var isPageValid = true;
                // Do nothing if client validation is not active
                if (typeof (Page_Validators) != "undefined") {
                    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
                        isPageValid = Page_ClientValidate();                       
                    } 
                } 
                if (isPageValid) {                  

                    document.getElementById('SubmitButtonOne').value = "Processing...";
                }            

                }
```

code behind:

```
protected void SubmitButtonOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        try
        {              
          // some functionality                   

        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
           //show errror message
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is expected behavior.

Once Page_ClientValidate is fired due to your explicit call inside PleaseWaitShow method and second is an implicit call made by the PostBack button click.

And so you are seeing two times the ValidationSummary message box.

I don't have a solution to circumvent this but will update if something strikes.

**Note:** One thing I would like to point out is since you have **ValidationGroup="Cases"** on your submit button you should pass that to your Page_ClientValidate method.

**Update 1:** One way I can think of is trying something like this:

1: `OnClientClick="return PleaseWaitShow();"`

2: return isPageValid from PleaseWaitShow():

```
function PleaseWaitShow() {
            var isPageValid = true;
            ....
            ....
            ....
            return isPageValid;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the expected behavior. Rather, it's a bug in ASP.NET validation JS code.

The `ValidationSummaryOnSubmit` function loops over all summaries, and for each summary, loops over all validators. If not group is specified, then each validator's message is appended, resulting in 2 (3, 4, 5?) repetitions of the same messages.

I solved the problem by fixing the function (staring at line 53 or so):

```
....

for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++)
{
    var validator = Page_Validators[i];

    if (validator.validationGroup != null && summary.validationGroup != null)
    {
        if (validator.validationGroup != summary.validationGroup) continue;
    }

    if (!validator.isvalid && typeof (validator.errormessage) == "string")
    {
        s += pre + validator.errormessage + post;
    }
}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use Page_ClientValidate method, you should set causevalidation to false. `CausesValidation="false"`

because Page_ClientValidate is already doing this for button or control you validate

Answer (score 0):

Please remove ValidationGroup of Button. Only user for ValidationSummary
Like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqvName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Please enter Name" ValidationGroup="SaveName"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClientClick="DisableButton();" Text="Save this Name" ></asp:Button>
    
 <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSaveName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="SaveName" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
```

Thanks